# Find equation of plane perpendicular to a line and tangent to a sphere.

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

Given a sphere with equation $$x^2+y^2+z^2=9$$ and the parametric form of a line, $$(x,y,z)=(1+2t, 1+2t, 1+2t),$$ find the equation of a plane tangent to the sphere and perpendicular to the line.

I know that there are two planes, but I only need to find one of them. However, I am having difficulty figuring out how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean that  $(x,y,z)$ is the parametric equation of the line ?

Comment: @Yassir yes, sorry.

Comment: Hint: Only the direction $(1,1,1)$ of the line matters ; therefore, the orthogonal plane has equation $1x+1y+1z=k$... It remains to find $k$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I am a bit confused. From there, what would I do?

Comment: Have you seen how one can express the equation of the tangent plane to a sphere like the one you have in a certain point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ ? Then express that it must coincide with plane $x+y+z=k$.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Jean Marie, the equation of the plane will be as

$$x+y+z-k=0$$

the distance from the sphere center to this plane should be the radius

$$\frac{|0-k|}{\sqrt{1+1+1}}=3$$

which gives
$$k=\pm 3\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the line is perpendicular to the plane,

and the line is parametrized as $(x,y,z)=(1+2t,1+2t,1+2t)$,

the equation of the plane is $2x+2y+2z=C$.

The points on the line satisfy $x=y=z$.

The line intersects the sphere when $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$;

i.e., $x^2+x^2+x^2=9$; i.e.,  $x^2=3$; i.e., $x=\pm\sqrt3.$

Therefore, the equations of the planes tangent to the sphere are $2x+2y+2z=\pm6\sqrt3$.